# Vue 3 - Load components based on backend setup

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I would like to setup a dashboard in vue 3 where the admin can customize the template a bit. In fact he should been able to define the sorting of components. At the moment the dashboard loads its components the default way in one column:

template:

```
<ComponentA />
<ComponentB />
<ComponentC />
```

Script:

```
import ComponentA from '@assets/components/componentA';
import ComponentB from '@assets/components/componentB';
import ComponentC from '@assets/components/componentC';
```

The backend sorting for the components is not yet finally written so i'm still very flexible it could be an array of the component names but i will be able to set this based on the Vue requirements. Unfortunately i did not found anything regarding such a functionality to "load components based on a custom configuration" and not "hardcoded".

can please anyone point me into the right direction how to archive such a functionality? Maybe with some small explanation. I've tried already to build something via the methods but all i've got was compiling errors...

In fact an admin should be able to set another sorting like:

```
<ComponentC />
<ComponentA />
<ComponentB />
```

**Additional note:**
All other parameters for the frontend are saved in a global "moduleConfig" object which is defined in the index file - thats because it will be filled by PHP. There is no need to change the dashboard in realtime, on page load all settings are given, so no update hooks are required. My target is to save the wanted struct there also in form of an array or so (as i said not fix defined yet).
Maybe:

```
let moduleConfig = {
     ...
     dashboardLayout: ['ComponentA','ComponentC','ComponentB'],
     ...
}
```